# Why changing from 4 to 8 in cx prints one more word? In Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

Ignore the comments and the variables names in portuguese.

```
org 100h

escrita equ 40h
ecran equ 1

;executa o ciclo 3 vezes
mov [cont], 3
ciclo1:
mov ah, escrita
mov bx, ecran
mov cx, 4
mov dx, msg
int 21h
dec [cont]
jnz ciclo1

;escreve ‘---‘
mov ah, escrita
mov bx, ecran
mov cx, 4
mov dx, msg0
int 21h

;executa o ciclo 5 vezes
mov [cont], 5
ciclo2:
mov ah, escrita
mov bx, ecran
mov cx, 4
mov dx, msg
int 21h
dec [cont]
jnz ciclo2

;aguarda que se carregue numa tecla
mov ah, 07h
int 21h

;retorna ao sistema operativo
mov ah, 4ch 
int 21h

msg0 db '---',10
msg db "UBI", 10
cont rb 1
```

This code produces the following output:

[image]

I want to know why when I change

```
    mov ah, escrita
    mov bx, ecran
    mov cx, 4
    mov dx, msg0
    int 21h
```

mov cx, **4**  to mov cx, **8**
The program prints an extra layer of UBI, instead of 5 it prints 6 times UBI after the "---"

[image]

Comment: Where and how `msg` defined?

Comment: Here msg0 db '---',10, msg db "UBI", 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changed code

```
    mov ah, escrita
    mov bx, ecran
    mov cx, 8
    mov dx, msg0
    int 21h
```

prints 4 bytes of `msg0` and 4 bytes following it. Let's recall the definition:

```
msg0 db '---',10
msg db "UBI", 10
```

The 4 bytes following `msg0` is exactly `msg`. So, instead of `---\n` you get `---\nUBI\n`. Then you proceed to printing 5 lines of `UBI`.

So you get an extra `UBI` line *before* the other `UBI`s, not after, which you might have suspected. You could check this fact by altering your `msg` before each output—e.g. by insertion of `inc [msg]` before `int 21h` in the `msg` printing loop and noticing that the first line isn't altered in the problematic case.